# Twitter api python поиск по тегами

Tags: python, twitter-api

стоит задача найти все сообщения по определенных тегам и записать в файл

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=("#море" and"#воздух")).items():
    print(tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
```

Сверху код поиска и записи. Как сделать поиск по 2 и более тегам. В данном случае выводит результат только по одному. Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у меня вот что вышло

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="#море AND #воздух").items():
    print(tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
```

вроде выполняет то, что нужно мне